# How to use .htaccess to redirect to another language contained in a subdirectory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am working on the translation of this website : https://villa-concarneau.fr

You will find a link in the menu to the english version.

You effectively land on the english version of the home page, but if you use any link on the page, you end up on the french version, while the URL is pointing to the english version.

The website is setted up this way :

Under root "/" you have the french version, and inside root, you have a directory "/en" for the english version.

"/" and "/en" contain 2 complete websites, one in french, the other in english.

I want to go from one another by clicking on the language link in the menu, which is "/en" when on the french version, and "/" on the english version. It is working fine.

But when using a link on the english version I end up loading the french version of the page linked.

Here is how the website loads its pages :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions Inherit

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^/en/(.*)\.html /en/index.php?tgt=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html /index.php?tgt=$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 404 /assets/php/404.php
```

The first RewriteRule is to force usage of HTTPS.
The second is intended to redirect all URL like "/en/something.html" to "/en/index.php?tgt=something" with a "L" flag to skip the following rules.
The third is the default rule : every URL like "something.html" is redirected to "index.php?tgt=something".

I am aware that the 3rd rule includes the 2nd, but as the 2nd is executed before if found and has a "L" flag, I thought it would do well.

Any hint wil be appreciated, thanks for your input ;)

Comment: Even with rewriting rules, you need to be careful on how your navigation links are written in your site. Did you check that all your links in the english version start by `/en`? or else they will redirect to french version

Comment: Good point Kaddath ! Sadly it is not the solution. But you are totally right to point it out as I've skipped this point. It is corrected now but the issue is still here.

Comment: can you check the http status for these en links? is there a chance we are falling into the very first rule (https one) and stop here because it is a [L]? In this case you should have a `301` in the console.. I would recommend adding a protocol condition anyway because you redirect even if you are https already. As a side note, i usually use `[QSA,L]` so that GET params in url are preserved (or else you don't want to)

Comment: The HTTP status is ok :
if I check with :
https://villa-concarneau.fr/en/grand-large.html, I end up with 200 and final destination status= 200
if I check with :
http://villa-concarneau.fr/en/grand-large.html , I obtain a 301 and a final of 200.
Adding the QSA doesn't affect this issue, and I don't use GET parameters in URL.

Comment: i'll look at it quickly if i have time, there is something unexpected here, when i enter this address : `http://villa-concarneau.fr/en/grand-large.html` (not https) i get this (the url is like this in browser address bar) `https://villa-concarneau.fr/index.php?tgt=https://villa-concarneau.fr/en/grand-large`, i think the 301 redirection shoudn't be a [L], unless there is a second .htaccess in `en/` that processes the english urls

Comment: You're right, there is a specific htaccess inside "/en" (and I might have to look deeper inside it...)

Comment: Well I found a workaround. But if someone as the solution, I am still interested ;)

Thanks!